# How to get value using components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and i am working on existing project,I am trying to get product review using component
but right now in my console showing me 0,How can i do this ?

Here is my file "pages/[slug].js"

```
import React, { useContext, useState,  useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Error from 'next/error'
import Image from 'next/image'
import ProductThubnailSliderSection from '../src/components/product/ProductThubnailSliderSection'
import RealtedProductsSection from '../src/components/product/RealtedProductsSection'
import ProductReviewSection from '../src/components/product/ProductReview'
import FlatRateSection from '../src/components/FlatRateSection'
import AddToCartButton from '../src/components/cart/AddToCartButton'
import {getProductExtraTag} from '../src/functions'
import WishListButton from '../src/components/wishlist/WishListButton'
import {AppContext} from '../src/components/context/AppContext'
import Link from 'next/link'

const Product = (props) => {
//const [productOverAllStarRating, setProductReviews] = useState(0)     
const [productOverAllStarRating, setProductOverAllStarRating] = useState(0)

  const router = useRouter()
  const { slug } = router.query
  const { wishListContext } = useContext( AppContext )
  if(props.error) {
    return (
        <Error statusCode={404} />
      )
  } else {
    const { product } = props
    const classToAddForAddToCart = "add-to-bag"
    let imageUrl = '/demo-product-img.png'
    let showProductThubnailSliderSection = false
    let relatedProducts = props.relatedProductsInfo
    let productImages
    if(product.images.length > 0) {
        showProductThubnailSliderSection = true
        imageUrl = product.images[0].src
        productImages = product.images.slice(1)
    }
console.log('Average rating is '+ setProductOverAllStarRating);
```

Here is my "ProductReview.js" file inside "src/components/product/ProductReview.js" file,I want to know that how can i get average rating or product and how can i fetch in my [slug.js] file ? Thank you in advance

```
import React, { useContext, useState,  useEffect } from 'react'
/* This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ */
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import cookie from 'js-cookie';
import Link from 'next/link'

import {AlertContext} from "../context/AlertContext";
import api from '../../../src/api';
import Pagination from '../../../utils/review-pagination'

function ProductReview( props ) {

    const  authToken  = cookie.get('token')

    const { pslug } = props
    const { showAlert, setShowAlert } = useContext( AlertContext )

    const [ratingValue, setValueRating] = useState(1)
    const [ratingQuality, setQualityRating] = useState(1)
    const [ratingPrice, setPriceRating] = useState(1)
    const [reviewText, setReviewText] = useState('')
    const [reviewTitle, setReviewTitle] = useState('')
    const [productOverAllStarRating, setProductOverAllStarRating] = useState(0)
    const [productOverAllRatingNumber, setProductOverAllRatingNumber] = useState(0)
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState('')

    //const [ratingPrice, setPriceRating] = useState(0)
    const overallRating = 3

    //** Set rating for value **/
    const handleValueRating = ( event ) => {

        setValueRating(event.target.value);
    }

    //** Set rating for Quality **/
    const handleQualityRating = ( event ) => {

        setQualityRating(event.target.value);
    }

    //** Set rating for Price **/
    const  handlePriceRating = ( event ) => {

        setPriceRating(event.target.value);
    }


    const handleReviewText = ( event ) => {

        setReviewText(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleReviewTitle = ( event ) => {

        setReviewTitle(event.target.value);
    }




    const [productReviews, setProductReviews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getProductsReviews = async () => {


            let authKey = Buffer.from(process.env.API_AUTH_USER_ID_KEY+":"+process.env.API_AUTH_USER_SECRET_KEY).toString('base64')

            let dataToSend = {
                pslug: pslug,

            }
            const res = await fetch(process.env.API_PATH+'/get-product-reviewlist/', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic '+authKey,
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            })
            const data = await res.json()

            if(data.success) {
                setProductReviews(data.data.reviews)
                setProductOverAllStarRating(data.data.overallRatingStar)
                setProductOverAllRatingNumber(data.data.overallRatingShow)
                setPagination(data.data.pagination)
                //const pagination = data.data.pagination
            } else {
                setProductReviews([])
            }

        }
        getProductsReviews();
    }, [pslug]);
```

Comment: Are you [slug].js your parent component and productReview child?

Comment: @ZiaYamin Not sure( as i said i am new in react) but i think "ProductReview" is parent but not sure

Comment: As i see you imported ``ProductReview`` to ``[slug].js`` so it is child.

Comment: You need to log the `productOverAllStarRating` but you are logging the function for setting the state `setProductOverAllStarRating` which you wont see the actual value

Comment: @VeRJil : can you edit in my code so i can check and implement in my side

Answer (score 1):

I thought in here `[slug].js` is your parent component and `ProductReview` Is your child, so you  can pass your value from child to parent in reacting like below:

**first in your `[slug].js` create a function `handleAverage` :**

```
function handleAverage(val){
   console.log(val)
}
```

**second, pass it as an `props` to your `ProductReview` where you used this component in you ``[slug].js**

```
<ProductReview handleAverage={handleAverage} />
```

**third, you can pass your `average` to this function in your `ProductReview` component:**

```
function ProductReview(props,{handleAverage}){
  .......
//here you can manipulate your average and then pass to handleAverage
// you can divide the all-star rate to product count... 
 handleAverage(productOverAllStarRating)
}
```

Comment: can you edit in my question/code ?

Comment: Which part of your code? you did not add any ``HTML`` part.